# How to get a bounds.size value from another controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am learning objective-C and I am stuck in a specific situation. Figure out the following situation:

> **ControllerA**

- It has the ControllerA.h, ControllerA.m and ControllerA.xib files.
- The Class of ControllerA.xib is associated to another controller. Lets say ControllerB. So, if you select ControllerA.xib file, click over "Identity inspector" and goes to "Custom Class", the Class is "ControllerB" and not UIView.
- From ControllerA.m I cannot access any parameter of the view, such as self.bounds.size.height. But I can access any parameter from an object created in this xib file, such as an UILabel

> **ControllerB**

- It has the ControllerB.h, ControllerB.m and NO ControllerB.xib file.
- From ControllerB.m I can access self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.height, but I cannot access any object create in the ControllerA.xib.

I have tried to solve this using Delegate, but I failed to pass information from one side to another. I want to keep the UIView class as ControllerB. Please, I need some help on this, can someone help me?

thanks,

Pedro.

Comment: are you using the interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some data from Controller A to Controller B or vice versa, do something like this:

```
//Controller1 Header (.h) File
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeClass *anObject;

//Controller1 Implementation (.m) File
@synthesize anObject;

//Controller2 Header (.h) File
#import "Controller1.h"
 -(id)getController1Object;

//Controller2 Implementation (.m) File
-(id)getController1Object{
    return Controller1.anObject;
}
```

Hope this helps!